# jQuery get the previous span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the previous span before the current, my code doesn't work.

```
<span class="badge votes">0</span>
<a href="#" id="up-vote"><span data-vote="up" data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
<a href="#" id="down-vote"><span data-vote="down" data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>
```

What I want is when i click the `span` with `class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"` and `class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"` to get the value in span with `class="badge votes"`

here's my `jQuery` code

```
  alert($(this).parent().find('span').text());
```

or 
`alert($(this).prevAll('.votes:first').text());`

Comment: Are those elements wrapped in a parent element? Are there multiple such blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.glyphicon').click(function(evt) {
  alert($(this).parent().prevAll('.badge.votes').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="badge votes">0</span>
<a href="#" id="up-vote"><span data-vote="up" data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up">Up</span></a>
<a href="#" id="down-vote"><span data-vote="down" data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down">Down</span></a>
```

Your `parent().find('span')` will go up to `<a>`, then look for a span in its children. `prevAll('.votes:first')` looks for sisters of the current span (which has no sisters). In both cases, you are stuck one level below from where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery's "closest" function to grab the span you are looking for like so:

```
$('span').on('click', function (ev) {
    alert($(ev.currentTarget).closest('.badge.votes').html());
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xj3mt7k/

Comment: No, they couldn't, because `.badge.votes` is not an ancestor of the click target. Did you test it? (I did; it returns `undefined`.)

Comment: Does it? You clicked the zero-width spans, did you, and got an alert that says `0`? Magic.

Comment: `.closest()` traverse the DOM tree upwards through its ancestors, starting with the selected element. Which is why if you click on 0 ('span.badge.vote') will get you a value of 0. Because the closest element is itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.badge.votes');
```

It will select the sibling of `<a>` with `badge votes`.

`span` selector can also work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty little trick:

```
$( "#up-vote, #down-vote" ).on( "click", (function( votesSpan ) {
    return function() {
        alert( votesSpan.text() )
    }
}( $("span.badge.votes") )) )
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4sbhmn9/

This can be taken even further and turn into a utility method.

Comment: Well, you are assuming that there aren't any more `span.badge.votes`

Comment: Not if each up/down span has their own badge (like on Reddit).

Comment: I seriously doubt he has more than one of each anchor tags with "vote-up" / "vote-down" ids on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers are flat out wrong, but all are too complicated.

`.closest('classname')` will return itself, so this is wrong.

`.parent()` will return the PARENT class, so this is wrong.

The code you're looking for is `$(this).prevAll('span:first').text()`

or for this specific example, `$(this).prev().prev().text();`

I tested both of these, and they work.  Just in general, think of it this way - you're navigating through HTML elements.  Look in your browser console at the nodes and you'll see the page hierarchy.  `.next()` and `.prev()` return the next sibling. `.find()` searches through children.